# Tkinter Combobox current function not working

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Hey there i've spent the last few hours diving through tkinters and my codes **dict**, I just can't seem to figure out why. I have a combobox that has 10 values loaded into it from a module called brownie. When the textvariable=account_index_val in the combobox gets updated I want to get the index of that option in the combobox list. So that I can use that index to get information from the accounts array from brownie.

I was able to get it to return the string value, essentially the account in a format like this '0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1', but I would much prefer to get it's index. I read up that the current function in the combobox widget would do that. But I get this returned when I try to print it.

```
anthony@ubuntu-machine:~/python$ brownie console                                                                                     │d
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum                                                                          │(1) 0x6cbed15c793ce57650b9877cf6fa156fbef513c4e6134f022a85b1ffdd59b2a
                                                                                                                                     │1
No project was loaded.                                                                                                               │(2) 0x6370fd033278c143179d81c5526140625662b8daa446c22ee2d73db3707e620
Attached to local RPC client listening at '127.0.0.1:8545'...                                                                        │c
Brownie environment is ready.                                                                                                        │(3) 0x646f1ce2fdad0e6deeeb5c7e8e5543bdde65e86029e2fd9fc169899c440a791
>>> import UserInterface                                                                                                             │3
>>> ui = UserInterface.UserInterface()                                                                                               │(4) 0xadd53f9a7e588d003326d1cbf9e4a43c061aadd9bc938c843a79e7b4fd2ad74
-1                                                                                                                                   │3
>>> ui.account_index_val.get()                                                                                                       │(5) 0x395df67f0c2d2d9fe1ad08d1bc8b6627011959b79c53d7dd6a3536a33ab8a4f
'Account'                                                                                                                            │d
>>> ui.ether_account_val_chooser.current                                                                                             │(6) 0xe485d098507f54e7733a205420dfddbe58db035fa577fc294ebd14db90767a5
<bound method Combobox.current of <tkinter.ttk.Combobox object .!frame2.!combobox>>                                                  │2
>>> ui.ether_account_val_chooser.current()                                                                                           │(7) 0xa453611d9419d0e56f499079478fd72c37b251a94bfde4d19872c44cf65386e
-1                                                                                                                                   │3
>>> ui.mainloop()
```

Here Everything Works, my Window shows up and i can select accounts, every account i select just outputs this. I'm assuming because of the last line of my code.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback                                                                                                        │4
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                   │(9) 0xb0057716d5917badaf911b193b12b910811c1497b5bada8d7711f758981c377
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__                                                              │3
    return self.func(*args)                                                                                                          │
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable                                                                                         │HD Wallet
Exception in Tkinter callback                                                                                                        │==================
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                   │Mnemonic:      myth like bonus scare over problem client lizard pione
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__                                                              │er submit female collect
    return self.func(*args)                                                                                                          │Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable                                                                                         │
>>>
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from brownie import *

class UserInterface(tk.Tk):

    ui_title_text = None
    eth_accounts = []
    for account in range(len(accounts)):
        eth_accounts.append(getattr(accounts[account], 'address'))

    account_index_val = -1
    upper_frame_hex = '#033b47'
    middle_frame_hex = '#075f73'
    bottom_frame_hex = '#3b4e52'
    ui_font = 'DejaVu Sans Mono'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.title("Camel Coin")
        self.geometry("600x500")
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        self.ui_title_text = tk.StringVar(value="Camel Coin Wallet")
        self.account_index_val = tk.StringVar(self, "Account")

        # Title Frame
        upper_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=100, width=500, bg=self.upper_frame_hex)
        upper_frame.pack(fill='both')
        upper_frame.pack_propagate(False)

        # Ethereum Account Frame
        middle_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=100, width=500, bg=self.middle_frame_hex)
        middle_frame.pack(fill='both')
        middle_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        # Camel Coin Frame
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(master=self, height=300, width=500, bg=self.bottom_frame_hex)
        bottom_frame.pack(fill='both')
        bottom_frame.grid_propagate(False)

        # In Title Frame
        ui_title_label = tk.Label(master=upper_frame, textvariable=self.ui_title_text, fg='white', bg=self.upper_frame_hex, font=(self.ui_font, 25))
        ui_title_label.pack(side='top', pady=25)

        # In Ethereum Account Frame
        ether_account_label = tk.Label(master=middle_frame, text=("Ethereum Account: "), fg="white", bg=self.middle_frame_hex, font=(self.ui_font, 10))
        ether_account_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, pady=5)

        self.ether_account_val_chooser = ttk.Combobox(master=middle_frame, values=self.eth_accounts, textvariable=self.account_index_val)
        self.ether_account_val_chooser.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=5, sticky='w')

        self.account_index_val.trace("w", print(self.ether_account_val_chooser.current()))
```

Interestingly, this function works on startup as it prints "-1" the default for the combobox.

Comment: `trace` needs function's name without `()` and later it will use `()` to run it - so you could create function with `print(...)` and later use name of this function, or you can use `lambda`  - `trace("w", lambda:print(...))`. At this moment your code works like `result = print(...)`  and `trace("w", result)` - so it runs `print()` at start and it assigns result to variable. Because `print()` returns `None` so you have `trace("w", None)`

Answer (score 0):

`trace` (similar to `command=`, `bind()`, `after()` in Tkinter)  needs function's name without `()` (so called `"callback"`) and later it will use `()` to run it.

So you should create function with `print(...)` and use only name of this function in `trace`

```
def show():
    print(self.ether_account_val_chooser.current())

self.account_index_val.trace("w", show)  # without `()
```

or you can use `lambda` for this

```
self.account_index_val.trace("w", lambda:print(self.ether_account_val_chooser.current())).
```

---

At this moment your code works like

```
result = print(...) 

trace("w", result)
```

so it runs `print()` at start (and you see `-1`) and it assigns to `result` value returned from `print()`. Because `print()` returns `None` so finally you have `trace("w", None)`

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given                    This is using your lamda method, and the function method is the same except it says 4 were given

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work i just put some random parameters in the show function and it worked

Comment: I never use `trace` but `mycombobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', show)` and I forgot that `trace` may run function with extra paramaters